# How to control where items get stored?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

If I have say wood in a chest with an IE Storage Bus hooked up to it, as well as the same type of wood in a barrel, how do I control where the item goes when I drop it into the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the priority of the Storage Bus. Shift + right-click the Storage Bus with the wrench and you'll be presented with a window that will allow you to raise or lower its priority. If you have more than one chest you'd like to attach to the network, it will try to insert into the one you set with the highest priority. If they are equal, it searches for another container with the same item and attempts to use it.